# In ionic app using router-outlet, but hardware back is not working in mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, routes, angular-routing, back-button

I am using ionic app with  for routing, In mobile application while doing hardware back the page is getting struck instead of moving to last page viewed. what can be the issue? I am not getting any console errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated to answer this question without any code..
But you can add a simple button to your HTML and set your routerLink. Something like:

```
<ion-buttons slot="end">
  <ion-button routerLink="/backToPage">
    <ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon>
  </ion-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

or like this:

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-back-button defaultHref="home"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

... if you have dynamic pages